# Was Christopher Steele told to stop collecting information about a Trump-Russia ties?

Tags: politics, donald-trump, russia, hillary-clinton

According to [The Hill](http://thehill.com/policy/national-security/400318-fbi-releases-heavily-redacted-documents-on-christopher-steele)

> They do, however, indicate that **Steele was told to stop gathering intelligence on behalf of the FBI in November 2016** — building on information already known as a result of the Justice Department’s recent release of surveillance warrant applications on former Trump campaign adviser Carter Page.

Did the FBI in 2016 tell Christopher Steele to stop compiling information on Trump and Russia?

Comment: Helpful link: https://thefederalist.com/2018/08/06/4-things-learned-fbis-mostly-redacted-steele-documents/, including a link to the original FBI documents.  One thing that's unclear to me is how we know that the "confidential human source" (CHS) referenced in those documents is Steele.  But Page 2 notes that "handling agent advised that CHS was not to operate to obtain any intelligence whatsoever on behalf of the FBI".

Comment: Assuming the CHS is Steele, the document essentially states that he was "fired" as an informant because he had revealed to a journalist that he was working for the FBI.  After that point the FBI no longer wanted anything to do with him.